# US citizen flying from Spain to Toronto with a Spaniard- customs/border difficulties?

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, canada, spanish-citizens

I'm a US citizen from Buffalo and I'll be flying into Toronto next week with my Spanish partner. My dad is picking us up from the Toronto airport and we're driving to Buffalo. My questions are:

Does my Spanish partner have to do anything special to enter Canada, like an ESTA form? He has his ESTA for crossing into the US.

If we have 5 bottles of wine between the two of us, is that ok? Is there a limit? If we have to pay duty on one of the bottles (say the limit is 2 per person), how much will it cost?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will require an [ETA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-start.asp) if arriving by air.  This is *not* required when crossing land borders.

The [duty-free allowance for Canada when entering from the US](http://www.dutyfreecanada.com/customs-allowances/) is **1.5L of wine per person**, so if your bottles are 750mL, you'll be one bottle over the limit.  The [Canadian duty calculator](http://www.canadiandutycalculator.ca/index.php) will help you figure out the cost; as an example, the duty on a bottle of 15% wine that costs $20 is quoted at $11.23.

Comment: But they **are** arriving by air to Canada.  Three months from now, this answer will be out of date.

Comment: Thank you jpatokal! That's exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @gerrit In three months, someone can edit the answer if necessary.

Comment: @gerrit Good catch, fixed!  I didn't realize they were driving from Toronto to Buffalo, not the other way around...